# How to install OpenCV3 in Anaconda3 offline?

Tags: python, opencv, installation, anaconda, menpo

I tried to install OpenCV for Python-3.5 in Anaconda using the following command

```
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv3
```

This is taking a really long time to download the file. It seems like my download accelerator is much better at doing this. The file location is at

https://anaconda.org/menpo/opencv3/3.1.0/download/osx-64/opencv3-3.1.0-py35_0.tar.bz2

Is there a way do the same installation offline given the `opencv3-3.1.0-py35_0.tar.bz2` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to install the package file directly then simply do

```
conda install PATH_TO_FILE/opencv3-3.1.0-py35_0.tar.bz2
```

Where, of course, `PATH_TO_FILE` to the file is just the path to the file. Note the warning in the `conda install` here:

> conda can also be called with a list of explicit conda package filenames
>     (e.g. ./lxml-3.2.0-py27_0.tar.bz2). Using conda in this mode implies the
>     --force option, and should likewise be used with great caution. Explicit
>     filenames and package specifications cannot be mixed in a single command.

You can also use the `--offline` argument to make sure you don't connect to the internet.

Comment: So simple, yet it worked; great! I just had to install the dependency `tbb` too and it worked like a charm.